# How to add custom user field (phone_number) in django default user table?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

I need to add a custom field called phone_number to the default django user table

Everything work fine but the phone_number field and value does not save in Table Django User.

Here is my custom form code

```js
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.EmailField(label="Email Address", max_length=254, help_text='Required a valid email address.')
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Required.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'phone_number', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Here is my view code for user registration

```js
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate Your  Account.'
            message = render_to_string('app/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()

            return render(request, 'app/account_confirm_message.html')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'app/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

My Model is here

```html
class Profile(models.Model):
    STUDENT = 1
    TEACHER = 2
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (STUDENT, 'Student'),
        (TEACHER, 'Teacher'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    # this method called for admin panel
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'profiles'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: Can you please add code of models.py where you defined phone_number in User model.

Comment: I did not define any field in model, please see the model code

Comment: If you already have a user profile model, why are you not using it?

Comment: Because I want to user fill the Phone_Number from custom user, That I used but I was able to add phone_number of user from Default django admin, I need to insert the flied from custom user registration form not  from default django  admin

Comment: You need to save phone_number somewhere either in user  or Profile. If you defined phone number in user model its will be saved by using form.save() but if you defined in Profile you need to assign value as 
   user.profile.phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number']
   user.profile.save()